# How do I not get blobs of a certain size displayed? (OpenCV, Python)

Tags: python, opencv, blob

I am in need of a function in OpenCV that allows me to not show blobs of a certain size, like in the picture where blobs are marked with a red circle, I would like for them simply not to be shown in an image.

This is the code I used:

```
    img = cv.imread('Fotos/1.jpg')
    params = cv.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
    params.filterByArea = True
    params.minArea = 8200
    params.maxArea = 15500
    detector = cv.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
    keypoints = detector.detect(img)
    #draw blobs
    img_with_blobs = cv.drawKeypoints(img, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255), cv.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
    plt.imshow(img_with_blobs)
    cv.imshow("Keypoints", img_with_blobs)
```

[Blobs detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY0kT.jpg)

Comment: I don't think you can get enough information out of SimpleBlobDetector to remove the regions you don't want. It only gives you a circular region (specifically, center and radius). Probably you'd have to use `cv.findContours` and `cv.approxPolyDP`. There are extensive [Python tutorials for OpenCV contours](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('input/1.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 51, 9)
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    if 8200 < cv2.contourArea(c) < 12500:
        cv2.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)
cv2.imshow("1", img)
```

[erased result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbHJ0.png)

Comment: Hi Mason, thank you so much for your feedback. That was actually the function I was looking for, just a small question:
what do you mean on this line: "cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]"
thanks in advance

Comment: API of cv2.findContours changed in 3.4.2. Before 3.4.2, cv2.findContours returned image, contour, hierarchy. after 3.4.2, cv2.findContours returns contour, hierarchy. so If len(cnts)==2 You use OpenCV >= 3.4.2 and You will get contour in cnts. If len(cnts) is not 2, You use OpenCV < 3.4.2 and You will get contour in cnts too.